# Issues With Restarting a While Loop In Python

Tags: python

I am trying to restart a **While** loop but am having issues. I've tried formatting the code several ways, and IDLE always returns with ">>>"

```
responses = {}

polling_active = True

while polling_active:
    name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
    response = input("Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ")

    responses[name] = response

    repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/no) ")
    if repeat == 'no':
       polling_active = False

print("\n--- Poll Results ---")
for name, response in responses.items():
    print(f"{name} would like to climb {response}.")

    response = input("\nWould you like to start a new poll? (yes/no) ")
    if response == 'yes':
        polling_active = True
        continue
    if response == 'no': 
       print("Thank you, have a good day!")
       continue
```

Comment: When you use a REPL, a blank line ends a block. So don't put any blank lines in the middle of the `while`

Comment: What is the error and what is the expected output? Please elaborate. Also what do you mean by "restarting" a while loop?

Comment: The error is that the code asks the user whether they want to start a new poll, or not, and when the user enters yes, nothing happens except IDLE returns with ">>>" 

The expected output is that the While loop is activated by the input 'yes'.

response = input("\nWould you like to start a new poll? (yes/no) ")
    if response == 'yes':

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your while loop in a seperate function like this:

```
def poll():
  while polling_active:
      name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
      response = input("Which mountain would you like to climb someday? ")

      responses[name] = response

      repeat = input("Would you like to let another person respond? (yes/no) ")
      if repeat == 'no':
         polling_active = False
```

Then, instead of calling continue at the end, simply run this function.

Answer (score 0):

Python is an interpreter language. The code runs from top to bottom. once it exits your while loop. it cannot return. Just use the function as mentioned in above answer.

Comment: Thank you! That is a very important piece of information that I did not possess until now.